# Generalize numpy.set1d to nd-arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to using numpy's setdiff1d function on nd-arrays :

```
import numpy as np

#a,b being ndarrays

in_a_not_b = np.setdiff1d(a,b)
```

But it does not work as it's working nd-array element wise.

e.g, if  :

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
b = [[7,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I want the output to be :

```
[[1,2,3]]
```

but here it would be :

```
[1]
```

Is there a simple way to generalize setdiff1d to nd-arrays ?

Comment: Some of the functions in numpy.lib.arraysetops have been generalized to deal with 2d arrays, such as `np.unique`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate the arrays `[b, a]` then check for uniqueness along `axis=0` and select only those indices that are greater than `len(b)` (i.e. unique values coming from `a`):

```
__, indices = np.unique(np.concatenate([b, a]), return_index=True, axis=0)
indices = indices[indices >= len(b)] - len(b)
result = a[indices]
```

This will return unique values of `a` along the first axis (but this is what `setdiff1d` would do anyway). The order of elements matters here, so if it shouldn't then you need to sort your arrays along the last axis.

Answer (score 0):

You can broadcast the arrays against each other, such that the last dimension is aligned, and then check that all elements of the last axis are equal and that this is the case for at least one element in the second to last axis (the arrays to check against):

```
mask = a[:, None, :] == b[None, :, :]
mask = mask.all(axis=-1).any(axis=-1)
result = a[~mask]
```

The order of elements matters here, so if it shouldn't then you need to sort your arrays along the last axis.